# Is it possible to use Selenium WebDriver for automating desktop applications?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, vue.js, electron, laravel-5.3, selenium-chromedriver

I'm preparing to write automated tests for Web/Desktop application that is currently in the initial stage of development. The technologies that will be used are Laravel, VueJS and most important Electron Framework. Electron is a framework for creating native applications with web technologies like JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

So I'm curious about **if is it possible to use Selenium WebDriver for automating desktop applications, which are created with web technologies (e.g. Electron)?**

I have succesfully wrote some Selenium/Java tests for "Slack Web Application" (Slack is developed using Electron framefork)

Now I want to try to use the same tests for testing "Slack Desktop App". If it is possible, maybe I can change "SetupSelenium" @Before Method?

This is my initial "SetupSelenium" method for Web based application:
@BeforeMethod

```
public void setupSelenium() {
    baseUrl = "https://slack.com/";

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\UOOP\\WorkspaceJava\\chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to(baseUrl);

    homePage = new HomePage(driver);
    signInPage = new SignInPage(driver);
    signInToYourTeamPage = new SignInToYourTeamPage(driver);
}
```

I appreciate help if anyone has any idea... Maybe to set binary path to slack.exe ??
To:  *C:\Users\Danant\AppData\Local\slack\slack.exe*

Answer (score 1):

You need to set some `ChromeOptions` when creating the `ChromeDriver`, like:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary(new File("C:\\path\\to\\slack.exe"));

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

There's a tutorial in the Electron documentation on this topic too: https://xwartz.gitbooks.io/electron-gitbook/content/en//tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code above but I received following error:

Comment: [2996:0115/154221:INFO:CONSOLE(24)] "(node:7180) DeprecationWarning: 'root' is deprecated, use 'global'", source: internal/process/warning.js (24)
About to fixup Slack Tray Icons against C:\Users\Danant\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.4.1\slack.exe
Failed to promote Tray icon: System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.
   at SlackNotifier.TrayStateChanger.<FixupSlackTrayItems>d__1.MoveNext()

Comment: at SlackNotifier.TrayStateChanger.<FixupSlackTrayItems>d__1.MoveNext()
About to fixup Slack Tray Icons against C:\Users\Danant\AppData\Local\slack\app-2.4.1\slack.exe
Failed to promote Tray icon: System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.
   at SlackNotifier.TrayStateChanger.<FixupSlackTrayItems>d__1.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing just electron apps, check out [spectron](http://electron.atom.io/spectron/) which is designed for this purpose.

When I'm testing the development version of my app I run tests like:

```
const Application = require('spectron').Application
```

...

```
beforeEach(function () {
  this.app = new Application({
    path: './node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe',
    args: ['./www/']
  });

  return this.app.start()
})

afterEach(function () {
  if (this.app && this.app.isRunning()) {
    return this.app.stop()
  }
})

it('shows an initial single window', function () {
  return this.app.client
    .getWindowCount()
    .should.eventually.equal(1)
})
```

To test a production app, just modify the `path` passed to the `Application` options.

Comment: Thanks. This solution probably works if you write code in Java Script. I prefer to write code in Java. My friends are much more experienced in Java Script than me and they told me that they have had problems with Spectron and Webriver IO. So I decided to try with Selenium.

Comment: Very true. JavaScript/TypeScript only. Although you wont have access to the electron APIs via Selenuim.